# Not able to install libssl-dev in ubuntu 18.04 for rvm

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to load rvm with for ruby 2.4 and rails 5 in ubuntu 18.04 but it depends upon libssl-dev. now installing it gives following error

```
vidur@vidur-desktop:~/rails_apps/tukaweb$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5) but 1.1.1c-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


vidur@vidur-desktop:~$ apt-cache show libssl-dev | grep -i version
Version: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5
Version: 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4
```

Comment: Can you show your apt repository settings? It seems that libssl-dev was found on multiple repos and apt simply wants to install the package with the highest version number. You can verify this with `apt-cache show libssl-dev | grep -i version`.

Comment: updated the result in the question @ClaudioKuenzler

Comment: Still, please show all the repositories active on this server. There seems to be the sury repo active, too? Make sure you have bionic-updates repo active, too. You may also just temporarily disable all the non-official repos to install the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint from Link: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4357

```
 1. sudo apt purge libssl-dev && sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
 2. rvm install 2.3.5 --autolibs=disable
```

Comment: suggestion update to rbenv.